# HCL Notes: How to increase limit for text?

Tags: lotus-notes, notesview, hcl-notes

For a project I am programming in HCL Domino and using a Notes Database. My problem is that the value I want to store as text is greater than the maximum limit for text (32KB).
As an alternative rich text came into my mind. Within the application it works just fine. Yet if I directly apply any changes in the database the text will be formatted differently. If I use the application again the text will be look something like this:

```
<font size="2" face="sans-serif">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;<br /> ...
```

But instead it should be xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ...
```

Is there any way to avoid this problematic? Is it even possible to change the maximum capacity for the normal text field? (with text it worked fine) For me it seems like the additional features of rich text like formatting text are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Torstens answer on using a non summary field, you can use the [Large Summary option](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/11.0.0/admn_increase_document_summary_data_limit.html) introduced in Domino 9.01 FP8 to increase the limit to 64K for text fields:

```
load compact -LargeSummary on database.nsf
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no Idea what you do to change the content of the text item as you do not provide any code what makes debugging nearly impossible. The easy way to achieve what you want is to use a NotesItem and set its "IsSummary" Property to False.
Be aware: Don't store a document with such a value in frontend, otherwise the 32k limit will come back. Here is some example code:

```
Dim bigItem as NotesItem
'- for new docs
Set bigItem = New NotesItem( doc, "NameOfYourItem" )
'- for existing docs
Set bigItem = doc.GetFirstItem( "NameOfYourItem" )

bigItem.IsSummary = False
bigItem.Values = "YourIncredibleLongValue"
```

You cannot show items that are non summary in views (same as Richtextitems), so depending on what you want to achieve this might not be a solution for you.